# Records between NOW() and 3am today or yesterday

Tags: mysql, datetime, between

How can I get records in a table between NOW() and the previous 3am?

This would be easy if it's 9am, but how do I write this if it's 2am? i.e I want the trades between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 HOURS) and NOW(). I'm looking for some code which can do both without needing to check the time in usercode and choose between two sql statements.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but it's eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple idea is to subtract three hours and compare the date:

```
where date(date_sub(col, interval 3 hour)) = (case when hour(date) >= 3 then curdate() else date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

Or, more explicitly, just do the comparison in SQL:

```
where (hour(date) >= 3 and date(col) = curdate()) or
      (hour(date) < 3 and date(col) = date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

Comment: Yes, I like this idea of subtracting 3 hours. It gets us back to thinking about all the transactions which occurred on a day rather than between 3am and 3am.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my own answer (I finally gave up and explored using IF and found it could be used inside SELECT statements), but @Gordon Linoff might be better - I've no idea which of these is faster.

```
SELECT IF (NOW() > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR),
           DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR),
           DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 21 HOUR))
```

which can then be used as the conditional on an outer SELECT.